# Xpages Domino Rest Services error while calling url with keys only on specific environment

Tags: rest, xpages, lotus-domino

I have a Xpage application which fetch the data on page load with url passed to the REST services which i created in xpages.

Normally if i call a REST service without the search key parameter in url it returns json data well, but if url contains the searchKey parameter, In front on the browser the simple error is "No Internet Connection". It means there might me some error thrown in server console, I checked the server console, I found this on every url Call with key.

The error starts below the red line
[image]

[image]

I can only guess that there is something to do with update on Domino Access Services. As per I can see to the error logs I cannot understand what is different in this environment.

Server 9.0.1
FP 9 installed.

Code of rest service

```
    <xe:restService id="restService2" ignoreRequestParams="true"
        pathInfo="searching">

        <xe:this.service>
            <xe:viewJsonService contentType="application/json"
                count="20000">
                <xe:this.columns>
                    <xe:restViewColumn value="test" name="column1">
                        <xe:this.columnName><![CDATA[#{javascript:var urlParam = context.getUrlParameter("column1");
if(urlParam != "")
return urlParam;}]]></xe:this.columnName>

                    </xe:restViewColumn>

                    <xe:restViewColumn name="column2">


                        <xe:this.columnName><![CDATA[#{javascript:var urlParam = context.getUrlParameter("column2");
if(urlParam != "")
return urlParam;}]]></xe:this.columnName>
                    </xe:restViewColumn>


                </xe:this.columns>

                <xe:this.viewName><![CDATA[#{javascript:var urlParam = context.getUrlParameter("aView");
if(urlParam == ""){

}
else{
return urlParam;
}}]]></xe:this.viewName>

                <xe:this.keys><![CDATA[#{javascript:var urlParam = context.getUrlParameter("searchKeys");
if(urlParam != "")
return urlParam;}]]></xe:this.keys>

            </xe:viewJsonService>
        </xe:this.service>
    </xe:restService>
```

the URL which i call to get the json data is

http://server/database.nsf/api_loader.xsp/searching?aView=Job0&column1=aTitel&column2=$7&searchKeys=ajit%20hogade

In above URL if I remove last param "searchKeys" it works perfect as expected

As per as I know that the "Key" in REST Service works equivalent to view.getAllDocumentsByKey("RequestedValue"), Here in my case "RequestedValue" is passed in URL param searchKeys.

Hope I explained it well.

Comment: You say this fails, "only on specific environment," but you don't really say what's different about the two environments.  This question could be improved with more details on the "good" environment.  In any case, this seems like an installation issue.  The `View.createViewNavFromKey` method was added in 9.0.1 FP8.  You are seeing `NoSuchMethodError` in 9.0.1 FP9, so perhaps there is an older version of Notes.jar on the classpath?

Comment: I can say that if we match with server versions then its both the same DOMINO 9.0.1 with fix pack 9

Comment: @DaveDelay at the installation part m not sure how to update the notes.jar and also where to find out the lastest jar in this case, it would be great if you can guide me ti get and download in this case. I think this will solve the problem.

Comment: Notes.jar is installed in **/{domino}/jvm/lib/ext** -- where **{domino}** is the Domino program directory.  I can't imagine the 9.0.1 FP9 installer would fail to update Notes.jar, but you could start by comparing Notes.jar on the "good" and "bad" servers.  Are the two files different sizes?

Comment: I think the problem has something to do with your wrong URL encoding ($ is not encoded correctly). This may lead to a bad search key (numeric and text mixed), which then fails.

Comment: @SvenHasselbach , I just tried without $ by editing the column name its still the same, any other suggesion on this? I am bit insecured because wherever needed in the application, I have used "view.getAllEntriesByKey("search_key"), if this is throwing an error then in the rest of the places same issue must be expected.

Comment: @DaveDelay, In this case you are wright, I have compared both the Notes.jar from working server and non-working server, Extracted jar and inside the notes folder i navigated to "lotus/domino" there is class View.class, I opened it in edited and try to find the function name "createViewNavFromKey" and i dont find any result on non-working server and found the same in working server.  Both the servers are feature Pack 9.Also I cant imagine that after update how notes.jar didnt got update.Anu suggessions how to update this notes.jar

Comment: @AjitHogade, you could try copying Notes.jar from the "good" server.  That might work, but I wonder what other files didn't get properly updated.  To repair the server, you might have to reinstall 9.0.1 FP9.  If you need more help on the install issue, you should ask a question here:  https://serverfault.com/questions/tagged/ibm-domino